# How to correctly sort merged arrays in Drupal 8 Twig template

Tags: sorting, twig, drupal-8

I'm new here for one question.

I have a node type in Drupal 8 with some fields referencing to taxonomy terms. I like to display these terms all together in one sorted array, so I merge the fields and sort them. But the result is always incompletely sorted, some terms are moved, but the others stay in the order they are saved.

I tried different ways for sorting:

- sort function:

  ```
  {% for t in node.field_x|merge(node.field_y)|merge...|sort((a, b) => a.entity.name.value < b.entity.name.value ? -1 : (a.entity.name.value > b.entity.name.value ? 1 : 0)) %}...{% endfor %}
  ```
- `strcmp`

  ```
  |sort((a, b) => strcmp(a.entity.name.value, b.entity.name.value))
  ```
- and I tried it with a twig extension function in a new module.

But it's always the same wrong result. So obviously I am wrong at some important point.

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have things like mixed `Taxonomy` and `taxonomy` casing in your terms?

Comment: An example of the said terms would help actually

Comment: I solved it with a theme_preprocess_node function.